# intertext with no numbering

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I'm trying to write this formula here

```
    \begin{align}
    L = 1 - \sum_{t \le x} \mathcal{N}(t | \mu, \sigma)\\
    \intertext{where $\mathcal{N}$ is the Gaussian density function }
    \end{align}
```

The problem is the numbering, I get (1) for the first line and (2) for the second. But I dont want the second to be numbered at all!

How do I do that?

Comment: Strange construction: can't you simply put the line of text outside the math environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You shouldn't type ``\\`` before `\intertext`

Comment: @campa isn't there the risk that if the equation is placed somewhere else by the LaTeX compiler?

Comment: What do you mean by "placed somewhere else"? If you fear a page break then you could use this construction (but removing the `\\\` as egreg said), but that's the kind of stuff I'd do at the very end of the typesetting.

Comment: As opposed to floats (which are typically used for figures and tables), equations are placed where you write them, if that is what you meant. So you can safely write the text after the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've missed your use case for an `align` environment. For the material you've shown, there seems to be no point in using an `align` environment, the more so as no alignment point is provided. I would use an `equation` environment.

Furthermore, I'd write `\mid` instead of `|`: `\mid` will make TeX insert a small amount of whitespace before and after the vertical bar.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
(some text before the equation\dots)
\begin{equation}
L = 1 - \sum_{t \le x} \mathcal{N}(t \mid \mu, \sigma)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the Gaussian density function.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\intertext` command should only be used if we want to preserve alignment across some text separating two parts of a display.

In this case `\intertext` can be preceded by `\\` (but is not mandatory).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
L  &= 1 - \sum_{t \le x} \mathcal{N}(t \mid \mu, \sigma) \\
\intertext{where $\mathcal{N}$ is the Gaussian density function}  
L' &= 1 + \sum_{t \le x} \mathcal{N}(t \mid \mu, \sigma)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\\` tells LaTeX that there *is* another equation, while `\intertext` is just ignored as far as equation numbering is concerned.

Having `\intertext` as the last item in a display makes no sense; the text will follow the display anyway. Your input should simply be

```
\begin{equation}
L = 1 - \sum_{t \le x} \mathcal{N}(t \mid \mu, \sigma)
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{N}$ is the Gaussian density function
```